# When did Rick Flag have a rag in his mouth?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, the-suicide-squad-2021

In *The Suicide Squad* (2021), Bloodsport says to Peacemaker:

> Bloodsport: I've been around Flag **when he's got a rag in his mouth**. Best not to tug it.

When did Rick Flag have a rag in his mouth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dog with a rag in its mouth won't let go and gets angry when you try to remove it.

[image]

In this instance, Bloodsport is saying that Flag's obsession with '*leaving no man behind*' is his metaphorical rag.